# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read' YAML reader

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml, pyyaml

After using py2exe to create an executable for my python 2.7 application, I get the following messages on running the exe file:

```
File "Mywebpagescraper.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "utils.pyc", line 4, in <module>
  File "dateparser\__init__.pyc", line 4, in <module>
  File "dateparser\date.pyc", line 11, in <module>
  File "dateparser\date_parser.pyc", line 16, in <module>
  File "dateparser\conf.pyc", line 61, in <module>
  File "dateparser\conf.pyc", line 31, in __init__
  File "dateparser\conf.pyc", line 45, in _get_settings_from_yaml
  File "yaml\__init__.pyc", line 69, in load
  File "yaml\loader.pyc", line 34, in __init__
  File "yaml\reader.pyc", line 85, in __init__
  File "yaml\reader.pyc", line 124, in determine_encoding
  File "yaml\reader.pyc", line 178, in update_raw
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I don't seem to know where the Attribute Error is coming from, the application simply crawl a web page using lxml library. I don't get this exception when I run the application within the IDE, everything works smoothly.

How do I go about solving this challenge?

Comment: Does the application work before it is converted to an `exe`?

Comment: yes, worked smoothly

Comment: You write it does work from the IDE, does it also work when started from the commandline?

Comment: Yes Anthon, worked well from command line